# Jax RS & Jersey with Junit; Test case is ignored

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, jersey, jax-rs

I can't get Jersey to work with Junit. Can anyone help here? I don't know what else to do.

I'm using my tomcat server, and when I run the project, I right-click the folder and select "run on server." After this is done, I am able to use a post-client in my web browser to use the web service and it works. I just cant get it to interact with JUnit. **It seems that it can't find the url, but I swear it works when I go to the post client.** 
what I expect the url to be is:

http://localhost:8080/propsub/webapi/new/getit

Here are the warnings + output that I get when I try to run my testcase with my tomcast server stopped:

```
Feb 01, 2018 3:30:31 PM org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest getDefaultTestContainerFactory
WARNING: Found multiple TestContainerFactory service providers, using the first found {0}
Feb 01, 2018 3:30:31 PM org.glassfish.jersey.test.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory$JdkHttpSe    rverTestContainer <init>
INFO: Creating JdkHttpServerTestContainer configured at the base URI http://localhost:8080/
Feb 01, 2018 3:30:31 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider com.liron.test.TestCases registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider com.liron.test.TestCases will be ignored. 
begin test case
end : 404 x:
```

Here is the output when my server is **on**:

```
Feb 02, 2018 9:49:09 AM org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest getDefaultTestContainerFactory
WARNING: Found multiple TestContainerFactory service providers, using the first found {0}
Feb 02, 2018 9:49:09 AM org.glassfish.jersey.test.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory$JdkHttpServerTestContainer <init>
INFO: Creating JdkHttpServerTestContainer configured at the base URI http://localhost:8080/
Feb 02, 2018 9:49:10 AM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider com.liron.test.TestCases registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider com.liron.test.TestCases will be ignored.
```

Here is my Junit class:

```
package com.liron.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.net.URI;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.TestProperties;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.liron.pojo.error.ErrorMsg;

public class TestCases extends JerseyTest{
    @Override
    public Application configure() {
       enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
        return new ResourceConfig(TestCases.class);
    }
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception{
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        super.setUp();
    }
    @Override
    public URI getBaseUri() {
        return URI.create("http://localhost:8080/");
    }
     @Test  
        public void testParseException() {
         System.out.println("begin test case");
         String json = "{\"test\":\"val\".}";
         //Response output = target("propsub/webapi/new/getit").request().buildPost(Entity.json("hey")).invoke();
         //String output = target("/getit").request().post(Entity.json(json), String.class);
         Response output = target("/propsub/webapi/new/getit").request().post(Entity.json("hey"));
          //System.out.println(output.getStatus());
           // assertEquals("should return status 200", "200", output.getStatus());
            //assertNotNull("Should return list", output.getEntity());
           String x = output.readEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println("end : " + output.getStatus() + " x: " + x);
        }
}
```

Here is the api:

```
package com.liron.webserv;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.liron.pojo.error.ErrorMsg;
import com.google.gson.*;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("/new")
public class New {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @Path("/getit")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getIt(String s) {
         System.out.println("begin getit");
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
                 .entity(new ErrorMsg("414","Testtesttest"))
                 .build();

    }
}
```

Here is the ErrorMsg pojo

```
package com.liron.pojo.error;

public class ErrorMsg{

    String errorCode;
    String errorMessage;

    public ErrorMsg(String code, String msg){
        setErrorCode(code);
        setErrorMessage(msg);
    }
    public String getErrorCode(){
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode){
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage(){
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage){
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

Application config:

```
package com.liron.config;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        System.out.println("begin getProperties");
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.memorynotfound.rs");
        System.out.println("end getProperties");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.liron.webserv</groupId>
    <artifactId>propsub</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>propsub</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>propsub</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>jersey.config.test.container.port</name>
                        <value>8080</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId> </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt400</artifactId>
            <version>6.7</version>
        </dependency>


         <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jdk-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.liron.webserv</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**EDIT UPDATE 1**
New output after changing my test case to include:

```
public class TestCases extends JerseyTest{
    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
        //return new ResourceConfig(TestCases.class);
        return new ApplicationConfig();
       //return new ResourceConfig().register(New.class);
    }
```

output:

```
begin getProperties
end getProperties
Feb 02, 2018 2:33:44 PM org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest getDefaultTestContainerFactory
WARNING: Found multiple TestContainerFactory service providers, using the first found {0}
Feb 02, 2018 2:33:44 PM org.glassfish.jersey.test.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerTestContainerFactory$JdkHttpServerTestContainer <init>
INFO: Creating JdkHttpServerTestContainer configured at the base URI http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: Edited to add a few of the changes suggested

Answer (score 0):

`return new ResourceConfig(TestCases.class);`

This doesn't do anything. You're supposed to register your resources classes with the `ResourceConfig`. The test doesn't detect any resource classes registered, so it doesn't run.

If you want to use `ApplicationConfig`, then just return that, since it is using the property to scan the packages

```
@Override
public Application configure() {
   enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
   enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
   return new ApplicationConfig();
}
```

As an aside, it pretty common to just register on the the resource you are planning to test. For example

```
@Override
public Application configure() {
   return new ResourceConfig()
       .register(ResourceUnderTest.class);
}
```

One benefit of this is that the success of this test is not dependent of any other resources initializing properly.

Another aside, instead of extending `Application`, generally in Jersey applications, you should extend `ResourceConfig` instead. And instead of using the `getProperties`, you can just call `property` in the `ResourceConfig` or just call `packages` to set up the package scan.

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationConfig() {
        packages("you.package.to.scan");
    }
}
```

Another thing, if you are using this Java style of configuration, the `web.xml` is not needed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "package("you.package.to.scan");" when I use the package keyword I get an error.

However, now it I dont get that warning but it still doesnt hit the service, any other ideas?

Comment: Oh, `packages`.

Comment: Also try removing the JDK test provider dependency

Comment: Can you be more detailed? Where do you see this? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I removed    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jdk-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>

but I got a 404 still when I run the test case (server is running before I do the test case)

Comment: Don't use `target("new/getit")` for the url